# zip() not running for a list with float values

Tags: python, list, sorting

```
sorted(zip(all_genres, glob_sums), key = float, reverse=True)[:3]
```

I need to print the top 3 values for my data but I keep getting the `'float' object is not iterable error`. `glob_sums` is a list of float values and `all_genres` is a list of the corresponding string values. How can I sort the list in descending order of `glob_sums` and then display the top 3 values along with their corresponding names?

Comment: `key = itemgetter(1)`

Comment: Please add some sample input data to your question so it's a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
sorted(zip(all_genres, glob_sums), key = lambda (genre,s) : s, reverse=True)[:3]
```

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error.

Comment: Does the error show where the syntax error is?

Comment: It showed it over : s after lamda. But I think I was getting the error due to glob_sums not being a list. It was a single value I generated using a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

sorted is attempting to apply the `float()` to each element of the iterable. In your case each element is `("some name", some_value)`. We can dip inside if instead we pass a function as the key!

```
sorted(zip(all_genres, glob_sums), key = lambda x: float(x[1]), reverse=True)[:3]
```

Comment: I still keep getting the float object not iterable error

Comment: Could you check if `glob_sums` is actually a list or just a value.

Comment: It was a single value. The code above worked. Thanks!